# Filter mlflow runs by commit ID

Tags: machine-learning, version-control, mlflow

When using the UI of MlFlow, is it possible to filter/search the runs using the (git) commit ID? I manage to search by parameters but it doesn't seem like there's a way to filter by the commit ID.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version (1.21.0) you can filter by commit hash with this search string `tags.mlflow.source.git.commit LIKE "truncated-commit-hash%"`. Probably this feature was introduced after you've originally posted that question.

Comment: Bear in mind that the commit hash stored by MLFlow is the full commit hash, not just the truncated "Version" shown on the UI. So you will need to enter a search string like `tags.mlflow.source.git.commit = "f79114340c86a44b0b8fadbdeae92a90770fa812"`

Comment: Good point @LeeNetherton, that also caused some headaches to me! In order to overcome this, I just use `LIKE` instead of `=`. That way I don't need to lookup the full commit hash in order to filter based on it. Updated my initial answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The search in the ui is translated to a rest api call to the mlflow tracking server:
[https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/rest-api.html#search-runs](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#tracking-ui)

You can see that you can search over 3 things: parameters, metrics and tags.

You can set the git commit id as a tag while training your model and then search for it, you can see how to set tags in the following [link](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#tracking-ui)